# How to find the repeat customers in the list?

Tags: mysql, sql

I Have Purchase Table Containing 5 Columns

Columns Names Are

> CustomerID, BillID, ProductID, unatity, Payment_Type

Columns Values Are

> CID00001, BID00001, PID001, 1, Card

Total Customers Count - 37156

DISTINCT Customers Count - 26053

How to Find the repeat Customers? (37156 - 26053 = 11103)

Answer (score 1):

Aggregation is one way:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) AS num_repeat
FROM
(
    SELECT CustomerID
    FROM purchases
    GROUP BY CustomerID
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) t;
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the list of repeat customers,

```
SELECT CustomerID, COUNT(*) AS PurchaseCount
FROM purchases
GROUP BY CustomerID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
SELECT * FROM Purchase 
WHERE CustomerID 
IN(
    SELECT CustomerID FROM Purchase
    GROUP BY CustomerID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    )
```